# How to convert a variable message to bytes in python 3?

Tags: python, networking, tkinter

Im working on a program for my networking class, its a client to connect to the professors MUD game he created, the client is supposed to send byte messages to the game server according the the protocol (http://isoptera.lcsc.edu/~seth/cs435/lurk_2.0.html) but im having trouble figuring out how to convert the variable input text from the user into the bytes the server uses which is little endian. i was mostly using the struct module, but would the to_bytes be better for it? On another note what would be a good way to translate the code?, because the text will have to be displayed in the center text box in the client.

Here is the code.

```
from tkinter import *
from sys import exit
from struct import *

userEntry = object

def button_func():
    print("Test")

def start_func():
    m = pack('i', 6)
    print(m)

def change_func():
    m = pack('i', 2)
    print(m)

def fight_func():
    m = pack('i', 3)
    print(m)

def pvp_func():
    m = pack('i', 4)
    print(m)

def loot_func():
    m = pack('i', 5)
    print(m)

def leave_func():
    m = pack('i', 12)
    print(m)

def submit_value():
    global userEntry
    print(len(userEntry.get()).to_bytes(2,'little')+userEntry.get())
    e1.delete(0, END)

class TestClient(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        global userEntry
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()

        for n in range(3):
            self.grid_rowconfigure(n, weight=1)

        for n in range(8):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(n, weight=1)

        lb1 = Listbox(self, width=20,height=24)
        lb1.insert(1,"Players Connected")
        lb1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='news')

        t1 = Text(self, width=60)
        t1.grid(row=0, column=3, columnspan=3)

        lb2 = Listbox(self, width=20,height=24)
        lb2.insert(1,"Connected rooms")
        lb2.grid(row=0, column=6, columnspan=2, sticky='news')

        la1 = Label(self, text="Value entry:")
        la1.grid(row=1, column=0)

        userEntry = StringVar()
        global e1
        e1 = Entry(self, width=40, textvariable=userEntry)
        e1.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=6)

        e2 = Button(self, text="Enter", command=submit_value)
        e1.delete(0, END)
        e2.grid(row=1, column=5, columnspan=10)


        b1 = Button(self, text="Start", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=start_func)
        b1.grid(row=2, column=0)

        b2 = Button(self, text="Change Room", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=change_func)
        b2.grid(row=2, column=3)

        b3 = Button(self, text="FIGHT", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=fight_func)
        b3.grid(row=2, column=4)

        b4 = Button(self, text="PvP FIGHT", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=pvp_func)
        b4.grid(row=2, column=5)

        b5 = Button(self, text="Loot", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=loot_func)
        b5.grid(row=2, column=6)

        b6 = Button(self, text="Leave", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=leave_func)
        b6.grid(row=2, column=7)

        stats = Listbox(self, width= 20)
        stats.insert(1,"health:")
        stats.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=8, sticky='news')

root = Tk()
root.title = "Test program"
tw = TestClient(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: A smaller example implementing a few of the packets would be easier to read! The Lurk Protocol doesn't seem to specify an encoding. Is it ASCII? UTF-8 may also be reasonable.

Comment: I try to separate GUI from back end functionality. For instance, I'd implement the client/server protocol without any tkinter dependencies at all. The GUI would be a separate module that interacts with it. One advantage is that I could write tests without having the GUI in the way. So, for me, I'd do `struct` and not `to_bytes`. Remember when doing `struct`, start it with `<`  for a little-endian encoding.

Comment: @tdelaney Can you give my an example of the < in a struct? im not sure where to put it in code.

Comment: I goes at the front of the `stuct`'s format string It just means "make this little-endian". Suppose I wanted to build the CHARACTER packet and I had all of the data in variabes. It would look like `packet = struct.pack('<B31sbHHHhHHH', pkt_type, player_name.encode('ascii'), flags, attack, defense, regen, health, gold, room, description_length) + description.encode('ascii')`

Comment: @tdelaney Ah i see now, just a few things though. what is the pkt_type? and the 31 in front of the s(char) character is that the length that the player name is supposed to be? lastly why is the description length and description itself separated like that with the + outside the pack?

Comment: @tdelaney I think im getting it, i added this code length = len(userEntry.get())                                                                                packet = pack('<' + (str(length)) + 's', userEntry.get().encode('ascii')) and i get b'Hello' when i input something like that into the entry, thats a byte type but im not sure if thats what i need.

Comment: Close. I'm not sure which packet type you are implementing, but they all have a fix-sized header and an optional variable-sized string after that. So, if its the fixed size PVPFIGHT for example, you need to pad out the name to a full 32 bytes. It would be `pack("<32s", 5, userEntry.get().encode("ascii"))".

Comment: @tdelaney is the 5 the variable-sized string? what is that for? i understand that a fixed sized header is required but the variable sized string im unclear on.

Comment: Looks like I typed that wrong. 5 is the PVPFIGHT message type. It should have been `pack("<b32s", 5, userEntry.get().encode("ascii"))`. The `b` means put the 5 in one byte. The `32s` means put the user text in the next zero-padded 32 bytes.

Comment: I did a variable length example above where struct.pack create the fixed length header and then I added the variable length `description.encode('ascii')` (assuming description was some string).